# Vlookup in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need this `vlookup` code to work in PowerShell.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,File_2.csv!$B:$C,2,false)
```

Basically, I have 2 CSVs and I need to retrieve the data from a specific column in File_2.CSV (2nd Column) and insert it in a new column in File_1.CSV.

**File_1.csv**

```
ID   NAME
--- ------
1    Alpha
2    Bravo
3    Charlie
```

**File_2.csv**

```
ID   STATUS
---  -------
1    Active
2    Inactive
3    Active
```

**Expected Result**

```
ID   NAME     STATUS
---  ------   -------
 1   Alpha    Active
 2   Bravo    Inactive
 3   Charlie  Active
```

My Code as follows:

```
#Initiate Excel
$path = Get-Location
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$path\file_1.csv")
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

#Add new column
$worksheet.Cells.Item(1, 3) = "Status"

#count column of A1
$colCountA1 = $worksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

#Setformula vlookup
$vlookup = "=VLOOKUP(B2,File_2.csv!`$B:`$C,2,false)"

#Add formula from C2 to Total Count of A1
$worksheet.Range("C2:C$colCountA1").Formula = $vlookup

$workbook.Close($false)
$excel.Quit()
```

The results im getting as of the moment:

```
ID   NAME     STATUS
---  ------   -------
 1   Alpha    #NAME?
 2   Bravo    #NAME?
 3   Charlie  #NAME?
```

but when I manually input the `vlookup` formula in Excel it works flawlessly. Not sure where im getting it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read one of the CSVs into a hashtable mapping the ID to the value:

```
$data = @{}
Import-Csv 'File_2.csv' | ForEach-Object { $data[$_.ID] = $_.STATUS }
```

then use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to add those values as a new field to the data from the other CSV:

```
Import-Csv 'File_1.csv' |
    Select-Object *, @{n='STATUS';e={if ($data.Contains($_.ID)) {$data[$_.ID]} else {'N/A'}}}
```

Pipe the result into `Export-Csv` if you need the result back in a CSV.

Comment: follow-up question - if there aren't any matches, how do i add a default remark (e.g "N/A")