# How to map or match the value from 1st table to 2nd table?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to map the value of my 1st table to 2nd table and I am following this thread but I dont get the values for computer. Am I missing someting with my code? Thank you in advance guys.

Thread: [Vlookup in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568501/vlookup-in-powershell)

**$ObjectTypesData:**

```
localAdminMember      ClassObject           ADClass
----------------      -----------           -------
member1               member1               computer
member2               member2               computer
User1                 User1                 user
Group1                Group1                group
                      NODATA                NODATA
Group2                Group2                group
Group2                Group1                group
                      NODATA                NODATA
```

**$data1:**

```
Object_Name           AccountNames       
----------------      -----------          
member1               member1             
member2               member2              
User1                 User1               
Group1                Group1               
Group2                Group2               
Group3                Group3     

     

$ObjectTypesData | ft
    $data = @{}
    $ObjectTypesData | ForEach-Object { 
        $data[$_.ClassObject] = $_.ADClass 

    } 
    $result = $data1 | Select-Object *, @{n='ObjectClass';e={if ($data.Contains($_.AccountNames)) {$data[$_.AccountNames]} else {'N/A'}}}
```

**Output**
**$result:**

```
Object_Name           AccountNames         ObjectClass
----------------      -----------          -------
member1               member1              N/A
member2               member2              N/A
User1                 User1                user
Group1                Group1               group
Group2                Group2               group
Group3                Group3               group
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense how are `member1` and `member2` getting N/A for ObjectClass when their ADClass is computer by looking at your first object...

Comment: I guess what @SantiagoSquarzon is trying to tell you is that there's no obvious problem with the code as posted, which means that no one will be able to help you unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello, Right! theres no problem with the code. Its my data and I did not see it right away. Thank you so much guys